# g++ compilation issue with array initialization

Tags: arrays, gcc

gcc compiles fine on the following code

```
enum AVMediaType {
    AVMEDIA_TYPE_UNKNOWN = -1,
    AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO,
    AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO,
    AVMEDIA_TYPE_DATA,
    AVMEDIA_TYPE_SUBTITLE,
    AVMEDIA_TYPE_ATTACHMENT,
    AVMEDIA_TYPE_NB
};

static int wanted_stream[AVMEDIA_TYPE_NB]={
    [AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO]=-1,   // Line 234
    [AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO]=-1,
    [AVMEDIA_TYPE_SUBTITLE]=-1,
};
```

but g++ throws the following error

```
playerthread.cpp:234: error: expected primary-expression before '[' token
```

What's the issue here?

Comment: Ask yourself what `[AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO]` should be supposed to evaluate to, and if that is something you could assign a value to...

Comment: That's not what it's doing. In C99 you can initalize elements of an array using this syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These kind of designated initializers aren't supported by g++, but they are by gcc. I'm not certain it's allowed in the C++ standard at all. You can see the same if you bring the code down to a very simple:

```
int array[10] = { [1] = 5 };
```

It's fine in C, not C++.

Comment: See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html for gcc's documentation of this feature.  This is standard in [tag:c99].

Comment: gcc will compile the above even with -std=c89 selected, which is surprising given that documentation!

Comment: So maybe I should just initialize the array *after* its declaration and move on.